# jQuery Menu Fading Out While still on links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery DropDown menu that seems to work pretty well with one minor, annoying issue. When you are randomly hovered over the menu the sub menu will fade out. Not always, only randomly. The other times the sub menu seems to show fine. So only randomly does the sub menu disappear. I don't know jQuery all that well, so I was hoping someone could see what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#solutions-btn').hover(function(){
    $('#solutions-drop').css('display','block');
    $('#quality-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#american-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#products-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#about-drop').css('display','none');
});

$('#quality-btn').hover(function(){
    $('#solutions-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#quality-drop').css('display','block');
    $('#american-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#products-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#about-drop').css('display','none');
});

$('#american-btn').hover(function(){
    $('#solutions-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#quality-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#american-drop').css('display','block');
    $('#products-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#about-drop').css('display','none');
});

$('#products-btn').hover(function(){
    $('#solutions-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#quality-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#american-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#products-drop').css('display','block');
    $('#about-drop').css('display','none');
});

$('#about-btn').hover(function(){
    $('#solutions-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#quality-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#american-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#products-drop').css('display','none');
    $('#about-drop').css('display','block');
});

var timer;
$('#main-menu a').hover(function(){
    $('#drop-menu').fadeIn( 200 );
},function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#drop-menu').fadeOut( 200 );}, 1500);
});

$('#drop-menu').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
},function(){
    $('#drop-menu').fadeOut( 200 );
});

});
```

JS Fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/20wfqzxz/

Hover over the links at the bottom. Hover them for a second and you will see that they disappear even while on the link.

Comment: Please create a Fiddle..

Comment: @user26409021 Updated with link. Thanks for any help!
http://jsfiddle.net/20wfqzxz/

Hover over the links at the bottom. Hover them for a second and you will see that they disappear even while on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your code into this:

```
var timer;
$('#main-menu a').hover(function(){
    $('#drop-menu').fadeIn( 200 );
    clearTimeout(timer);
},function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#drop-menu').fadeOut( 200 );}, 1500);
});

$('#drop-menu').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
},function(){
    $('#drop-menu').fadeOut( 200 );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20wfqzxz/2/)..Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a stop animation function before doing any other animation. E.g., `$('#drop-menu').stop().fadeIn( 200 );` and `$('#drop-menu').stop().fadeOut( 200 );` So these animations won't ruin each other.

Answer (score 0):

First, stop animation before starting new animation.

```
$("#drop-menu").stop();
```

Second, remove the timer and settimeout commands - you won't need them if you stop the animation!